# Checking a user's in-app purchase status from another user's perspective

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

My original plan for the iOS app I'm developing was to make it free for all users except for administrators of "organizations" stored in a cloud database. These administrators pay a monthly subscription fee to maintain these organizations, and free users join them. An organization's administrator is the only one who can accept new users and set user permissions.

However, I realized that I have no way to check whether an administrator's subscription has expired from the point of view of another users, meaning it may be possible for an administrator to get a free trial, set up an organization, join it from an alternate account, set up permissions, cancel the subscription, and continue using the app as normal without paying. Currently, the only case that the app can handle is if the administrator tries to log into an organization after the subscription has expired.

I planned to avoid this issue by having "active" and "inactive" states for organizations stored in the database, but I still need a way for the app to recognize that a subscription has expired and deactivate the organizations associated with the user in question. I'm not sure how to do this, other than from the point of view of the admin, who could simply stop using the account before the subscription expires, and/or delegate management of an alternate, non-admin account to someone else.

I also realized that this specific setup might violate Apple's policy on in-app purchases, since I am effectively indirectly taking functionality away from free users due to paid users' subscriptions expiring. If this is the case, I'll have to rethink the payment structure of my app entirely. Am I allowed to handle subscriptions this way? If so, how can I a) reliably ensure that my app disables an organization when its admin's subscription runs out, or b) check whether an admin's subscription has run out when another user in the organization tries to log in?

Comment: I would store the subscription expiration date against the organisation in your database.  Then you can easily check whether the subscription is active and take appropriate action in your "user" app.  Each time the administrator runs their app you check the app receipt and update the expiration date in the database

Comment: Thanks! I I'm now looking at ways to check the app receipt. I found this: http://savvyapps.com/blog/how-setup-test-auto-renewable-subscription-ios-app but I can't seem to get the sample code for receiptValidation() to compile... do you know where I could find a Swift 3-compatible version?

Comment: You need to validate the receipt on a server.  I created a PHP script - https://gist.github.com/paulw11/fa76e10f785e055338ce06673787c6d2 and hosted it on Google App Engine.  The Swift code is just a straight forward HTTP post with and decode the JSON response.  You need to substitute "%2b" for any occurrences of "+" in your base64 encoded receipt when you POST it or the validation will fail